# How to update Redux store on all devices running an app?

Tags: android, react-native, redux

In a react native app that has multiple users on separate devices, there is some data that varies depending on which user is logged in and other data which should be updated for all users on all devices. For example, if the users are able to submit posts they should be able to see and edit their own posts when logged in and this data would be different depending on which user is logged in on a device. Whereas an object containing all posts, should be updated for every user's app/device.

```
export default reducer = combineReducers({
    posts: postsReducer, // same for all users on all devices
    user: userReducer, // different depending on user on specific device
})
```

I am relatively new to redux and my understanding is that `store.dispatch` updates an app's store locally, on only the current device. However I want to know how to update data for every device which has the app downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Google's Firebase allows apps to have a simple database which can then be used to query information that the specific user has the rights to access.